# How to create a user listing page with a tpl.php

Tags: 7, views, users

I would like to create a listing page of users of a particular role.

Inside this view, there should be another view which shows the related content for each user.

When I try to create a view the system gives me the option to use just fields, but I need to be created like a node so I can use a tpl.php file.

How can I get a tpl.php file for this?

If I create a view for the users and one with the contents(contextual filter uid), can I embed  the second view inside the view-unformatted.tpl.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I create similar page with views: http://cgart.ir/en/members

as you can see there is a list of users and 5 last uploaded image. the page created with views and latest artworks is another views.

to do that:

1. create first view for list users and in `Format` select `Show:Rendered entity | Settings`
2. create second view and configure `CONTEXTUAL FILTERS` and add `Content: Author uid`

edit `user-profile.tpl.php` and render second view there:

```
$account = $variables['elements']['#account'];
<?php print views_embed_view('second_view', 'page_1', $account->uid); ?>
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for you answer, it does almost what I want. If you cloud tell me just the last thing. If i want to not affect the profile page it-self, in temrs of views and style, should I manage it through css? For example a want a box to be shown on the listing page but not in the profile page. How can I do this?

Comment: you can add new `view mode` to profile via `hook_entity_info_alter()` and with `$view_mode = $variables['elements']['#view_mode'];` you can make difference in `full` and `list` mode of user profile... let me know if it's not enough...

Comment: $view_mode is like $page? It makes differences beetwen listing and node? Now I will do some research. If I need suggestions, I will write it here.

Comment: go to views setting and in `Show:Rendered entity | Settings` select another `view mode` for list